# Who should own the pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-management

While programming, many times I've come across the following design choice: The user creates an object and passes it to some other object which processes in some way in a second stage.

As an example, you could imagine a raytracer. The user creates a sphere with certain properties and calls `raytracer.addTraceable(sphere)`. Now, there are three ways I can think of doing this.

1. The raytracer becomes responsible of deallocating the memory allocated to the sphere object
2. The user needs to deallocate the memory allocated to the sphere object.
3. The raytracer just copies the sphere object and both user and raytracer deallocate their local copy.

Generally what is the best design choice in such a case? Are there any other options besides the ones I mentioned (not including smart pointers)?

PS: I've come across the same problem in plain C when using an object oriented approach.

Comment: Why exclude smart pointers?

Comment: Do you consider explicit reference counting to be part of "smart pointers"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The consistent use of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) makes this a moot point. Using a smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr` the object is owned by *all* of the pointers and it is deleted after the last pointer is destroyed.

C doesn't really have a convenient way to express the RAII idiom.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, in the example I gave, the raytracer should handle the destruction of the object because it is the only code that can do that if it runs into an exception?

Comment: @Grieverheart, with smart pointers you don't need to worry about who handles destruction. It happens automatically.

Comment: I agree to Mark Ransom - RAII would be a choice in such situation, if it's applicable. Unfortunately author didn't specify why he wants to avoid smart pointers, may be he cannot use 3rd party libraries or C++11, but RAII is 4th option that hasn't any cons of previous 3.

Comment: As I commented on jxh's post. Sometimes I have to iterate over the objects in a very tight loop (I'm running physics simulations). Although I wasn't overly specific about it in my question I'd also like to have a solution that would work for C.

Comment: @Grieverheart The best solution is going to depend highly on whether you're using C or C++, they really are two different languages despite the similarities and history. It's best not to ask for a single solution for both. There's no obvious answer for C as there is for C++.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you realize that a smart pointer will solve your issues for you, but that you are dismissing it for a reason you don't explain. (Maybe because your code really has to work for both C and C++?)

If the `sphere` object is being managed by the `raytracer` object, then logically it takes ownership of the object. However, you left out a choice that would work well for this application:

- The user supplies the properties of the object to be added to the `raytracer`, which is then responsible for creating and destroying the object.

The `raytracer` then becomes something like a factory, and the properties object is something like a builder.

Comment: This is similar to option 3, a proxy class that holds the properties could be used instead.I generally like to avoid smart pointers because I'm writing performance-critical code.

Comment: Are you sure that the smart pointers would be a bottleneck in your application? I'd at least try using them, benchmark and then decide if I'd ditch them or not.

Comment: @Grieverheart: I don't deny it is similar, but it effectively addresses the problem of object ownership, which was what your question was really about. The overhead of reference count manipulations can be avoided in a tight loop by using a reference to the smart pointer, or getting the bare pointer itself, when using the pointer within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

All three ways might be correct from design point of view, there are always pros/cons:

1. Change ownership existed in C++ in a form of auto_ptr. The cons would be code maintenance, for example in raytracer you have always to keep in mind how object was allocated, from which heap. If raytracer is implemented in 3rd party dlls having separate heap it would fail in debug mode and memory leak in release.
2. If raytracer user has to deallocate memory - it has to track raytracer, means it has to take ownership, depending on implementation it might add unnecessary code complexity.
3. Copy object would be a perfect solution except the cases when the original sphere object changes must be tracked in raytracer or copy impacts performance or is impossible at all.